# Grok custom time format

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a time format like below.

```
2017-10-15T06:25:02.186227-04:00
```

This seems to work partially `%{NUMBER:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}T%{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minutes}.%{SECOND:second}`

Comment: it should be parsed with standard `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}`, and then convert it to date with `date` filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern should work with a colon before the second pattern up until what i assume is a timezone. Then we can use a custom field capture for that.

```
%{NUMBER:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}T%{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minutes}:%{SECOND:second}(?<timezone>[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})
```